# Unable to Submit a Form with 4 file upload fields on IE9

Tags: html, file-upload, internet-explorer-9

I am unable to upload a form with 4 file upload fields on IE9/Win 7.

I am trying to upload 4 files using a multipart form.

It works fine for 1/2/3 files but somehow doesn't work when I am selecting 4 files.

Here is a link to the sample form:

http://so.nettantra.com/test-upload.php (Its Valid HTML5 and works on Chrome/Firefox/Safari but not IE9/Win 7)

Comment: doesn't work how? doesn't upload at all? 4th file doesn't show up? Did you bother looking at the `['error']` parameters in $_FILES for non-zero values?

Comment: It doesn't complete the request. It just gets stuck saying "waiting for response".

Comment: I have a `print_r($_FILES);` in the sample form as well.

Comment: submitting 4x13byte files on IE9/win7-x64 works fine here.

Comment: Did you try with the same file for all the 4 fields? I works when all the 4 fields have the same file. Please try using 4 different files.

Comment: it was 4 different files. "echo > 1.txt", "echo > 2.txt", etc.. then stuffing each file into one of the file selects.

Comment: Can you try with 4 different files may be image, doc or xls files?
I have been trying with some real files (of different file types, jpeg, png, doc, pdf) not very large around 100~150 Kb Size .. It doesn't complete the request.

Comment: I have been trying to get something from Fiddler. It just says:/test-upload.php Body: -1 . There is no response. Only the request. Although the TextView in the Inspector shows all the fields are being sent.

Comment: Watch the upload in Fiddler. What does Fiddler show? What state does it claim the session is in (right-click the request and choose Properties. State is shown at the top). Also, do you have any third party download managers (e.g. "FreeDownloadManager") installed? Those are known to foul up the internal behavior of URLMon and cause problems exactly like this.

Comment: In fiddler this the value of session state "SESSION STATE: ReadingResponse. "

Comment: I do not have any third party download managers.

Comment: I have no problem whatsoever in uploading four files to the server in question. What, if any, browser add-ons do you have installed? If you start IE using `iexplore.exe -extoff` is there any change? If you send me a Fiddler .SAZ file showing the upload, I'd be happy to look at it.

Comment: I have uploaded the .saz file to http://so.nettantra.com/test-upload.saz . Please have a look at it and let me know if you can find some clue.

Comment: I ran with `iexplore.exe -extoff`, there was no change. The request doesn't get a response and just gets stuck.